# Python Selenium verify record is deleted

Tags: python, selenium

I have this code in python and selenium to find the deleted records and verify that the record is deleted.

```
def find_deleted_device(self, mac, serialno):
    index = 0
    loopNext = True
    matched = False
    while loopNext:
        index = 0
        if not element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.no_device):
            record = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.devices_record)
            macaarray = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.device_record_mac_address)
            serialnum = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.device_record_serial_number)

            for facility_mac, serialnumber in zip(macaarray, serialnum):
                if facility_mac.text == mac and serialnumber.text == serialno:
                    loopNext = False
                    matched = True
                    break
                elif index == len(record) - 1:
                    if index >= 19:
                        next_page = element_locator.find_element_by_css(driver_obj, self.nextpageselector)
                        if next_page.is_enabled():
                            next_page.click()
                        else:
                            loopNext = False
                    index = index + 1
                else:
                    loopNext = False
        else:
            print('No matching macaddress and serial number, No device message appears')
            assert True
            loopNext = False

    if matched:
        print "The mac and serial number matched, should have been deleted"
        assert False
    else:
        print('No matching macaddress and serial number found')
        assert True
sleep(2)
```

But the problem is there are two scenarios:
1) If only one record exists and we delete that then I get a message "No Records exist" 
2) second scenario is a few records exists and I can loop through and verify that the record is deleted.

In case of scenario 1, it works fine.
In case of scenario 2 , it passes but with an error something like  "1496424768.39". How do I escape this error.

Comment: One issue with selenium is when we define an element , it always tries to find it no matter what and gives an error. How do I escape from that. I tried this also record = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.devices_record)
            if record is None:
                print "Record is none, No records found"
                assert True
                break

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my issue using the following alternative approach.

```
#This method is used to search deleted group
    def find_deleted_device_with_paging(self, mac, serialno):

        page_num = element_locator.find_element_by_css(driver_obj, ".test-grid-pagination-summary")
        if page_num.text < 1:
            print('No matching macaddress and serial number found')
            assert True

        else:
            index = 0
            loopNext = True
            matched = False
            print "The mac and serial number matched, should have been deleted"
            while loopNext:
                index = 0
                record = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.devices_record)
                macaarray = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.device_record_mac_address)
                serialnum = element_locator.find_elements_by_css(driver_obj, self.device_record_serial_number)

                for facility_mac, serialnumber in zip(macaarray, serialnum):
                    if facility_mac.text == mac and serialnumber.text == serialno:
                        loopNext = False
                        matched = True
                        break
                    elif index == len(record) - 1:
                        if index >= 19:
                            next_page = element_locator.find_element_by_css(driver_obj, self.nextpageselector)
                            if next_page.is_enabled():
                                next_page.click()
                            else:
                                loopNext = False
                        index = index + 1
                    else:
                        loopNext = False

            if matched:
                print "The mac and serial number matched, should have been deleted"
                assert False
            else:
                print('No matching macaddress and serial number found')
                assert True
```

So, Instead of verifying the message ,I am comparing the number of records that exist on that page for pagination purpose. This fixed my code.